# Wavefunction of particle in power law potential of type $x^a$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

How could we calculate the wave function of a particle under a potential of form $V(x)=x^a$?

Is there any analytical solution or any general feature of such solution (like its an exponential function).

Comment: A harmonic oscillator has an x^2 potential (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) and has an analytical solution

Comment: It's possible to do a pretty elementary calculation to estimate the energies. See http://www.lightandmatter.com/area1sn.html , ch. 13, problem 43.